# Include root files into header files

Tags: themes, wp-blog-header.php

I want to include files from the root directory of my site within the WordPress "header" file.

Is there any function for including a file from the root folder?

Comment: There is no specific function other than PHP`s `include`. Also please specify if you use WordPress itself in the root, and how you set up your system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the WordPress root, use:

```
include ABSPATH . "/extra-file.php";
```

`ABSPATH` is always the WordPress root, you can see that in your `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `wp-config.php` file, add the following line before `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`:

```
define( 'ROOT_FOLDER', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
```

Now you can use the following for including files from your root folder:

```
include ROOT_FOLDER . '/filename.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "include" some CSS or Javascript (i.e. if you're not talking about `PHP include`), use the function `get_site_url()`.

Example usage:

```php
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/example_javascript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Its as simple as this.

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/yourfile.php");
```

Cheers!!

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not always the root of the WordPress installation.